# Echo dot light colours customisation

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

Is there any provision to manage the light ring on echo device? For example, for certain events, I want to change echo device light ring to red. Can we do that using Alexa skills kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light colours are used as a security style feature to highlight when the Echo is actively listening, not just waiting for its wake word.

The only other time that it changes colour is a lack of WiFi which again indicates that it cannot 'actively listen'.

They are not currently controllable from the SDK

Comment: The light now also glows green when a message is waiting.